# How do I make Visual Studio 2022 use chrome

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have created a new Angular with .NET Core application using Visual Studio 2022, version 17.8. I have specified Chrome as my default browser, here:

[image]

But whenever I debug, it starts up Edge for both the client and the server projects.

Can anyone tell me how to get Visual Studio to open these projects in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the setting in the screenshot does not have the expected effect, but I found that I could change the default browser for each individual project by:

1. Choosing the individual project to be the ONLY startup project (instead of starting multiple projects); then
2. Choosing the browser from what will then replace the "Start" button.

After doing this, I could then go back to the solution and select multiple startup projects, and they used the individually configured settings.